# Ruby koans: Koan 262 - what is going on here?

Tags: ruby

Been working through the Ruby koans and I'm up to 262. I've solved it as follows:

```
def test_catching_messages_makes_respond_to_lie
    catcher = AllMessageCatcher.new

    assert_nothing_raised do
      catcher.any_method
    end
    assert_equal false, catcher.respond_to?(:any_method)
  end
```

...but I have little idea what this code is doing. I've looked up assert_nothing_raised, but the docs are very sparse and esoteric in their explanation. I understand that this lesson is supposed to teach me that respond_to? 'lies' in certain circumstances, but what is the circumstance here?

Is it that the :any_method doesn't exist? Does it NOT exist if it's defined in the block for assert_nothing_raised? What, in short, the hell is going on in this code?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's the WellBehavedFooCatcher class:

```
class WellBehavedFooCatcher
    def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
      if method_name.to_s[0,3] == "foo"
        "Foo to you too"
      else
        super(method_name, *args, &block)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert_nothing_raised` asserts successfuly when nothing has been raised in the given block ;-) In this case when the method call was successful.

Regarding method calls being successful even if there is no method with this name: Ruby has a special method [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) which gets called when the original method doesn't exist:

```
class A
  def method_missing(the_id)
    puts "called #{the_id.inspect}"
  end
end

A.new.foo
```

This gives you a `called :foo`. The `respond_to?` call just checks if the object *directly* responds to the method call, so if `method_missing` is responding it will return false.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still don't understand why the assert_nothing_raised is there. Isn't the respond_to? just checking for a :any_method method? And assuming the missing_method is doing it's job, you'd EXPECT it to return true, but the lesson is saying it returns false, as a 'surprise', right? So what's the assert_nothing_raised doing? Why is it even there?

Comment: @moosefetcher I added some more explanations. The `assert_nothing_raised` is there to show you that the method call succeeds (due to the `method_missing`) but `respond_to?` returns false (since the object doesn't really respond to the message)

Comment: Ah - I see! Thanks again. I'm not sure if this is worth asking another question, but I'm also not clear why, in that koan ruby file, the 'WellBehavedFooCatcher' class defined a few lines before is able to call 'super' when it doesn't inherit from anything... Any idea?

Comment: [All classes derive from `BasicObject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/BasicObject.html) (directly if no other superclass exists or indirectly if there is a superclass).

Answer (score 0):

To put it another way...

`catcher` is an instance of a class that responds to any method called on it (by catching  with `method_missing`).

The call `catcher.any_method` demonstrably succeeds.

Yet the call `catcher.respond_to?(:any_method)` demonstrably returns false.

So catching messages makes `respond_to?` lie.